# How to find nonzero elements in a square matrix mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have a matrix with both zeros and ones, in Matlab we just use the `find` command to find the indexes of those nonzero elements. But how can we find it mathematically? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What do you mean by "find it mathematically"?

Comment: There must be some mathematics going behind the function 'find' let say in MATLAB, or is it just binary search, matching each element one by one if it is true or false and then returning the index... for example i need to find the number of 1's i can sum all the columns and and then again sum the row it will give me the total number of 1's.

Comment: something similar, but what i am asking is the positions of zeros are completely random...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231557/calculating-number-of-non-zero-elements-in-a-lower-triangular-matrix/231607#231607?newreg=827361f7486042a09bc0f18e71658c3c

Comment: Are you asking about notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{ (i, j)\ |\ a_{i,j} \ne 0\}$$

where $a_{i,j}$ is the element at row $i$, column $j$.

Comment: @lhf edited per your comment